# React Virtualized grid text wrapping breaks the layout

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

When table wraps the multiline text it will break the grid layout and start to go under other items in the grid. **(Image below)**

Im currently using React-Virtualized with AutoSizer and it had been working fine till we needed to use text which uses more than 1 line of text in table.

The grid layout will not break if i set rows to noWrap, but the text needs to wrap for obvious reasons.

Any idea how this could be fixed? If needed i can try to create a small jsfiddle showcasing the problem since i cannot show the code of the project.

[image]